# Javascript/Jquery countdown to date script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a script that counts down to a specific date with the format day, hours, minutes.

I have trying to mess around with this but it didn't work at all.

```
var end = new Date('31/06/2014 10:1 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring an invalid end date. Change this and all will work.

```
var end = new Date(2014,6,31,10,1,0); //new Date('31/06/2014 10:1 AM');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't seem to accept European-style day-first dates. Also, 10:1 isn't a valid time.

```
var end = new Date('06/31/2014 10:01 AM');
```

To avoid confusion, maybe just name the month:

```
var end = new Date('June 31, 2014 10:01 AM');
```